# What is the impact of compression on query performance in Elasticsearch?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, compression

What is the impact of compression [best_compression] on query performance in Elasticsearch? Specifically for below types of queries:

- search
- aggregate
- regex
- range
- time range

Will compression even impact all these queries? If not, specifically what type of queries will be impacted?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on at least these factors:

- size of a cluster
- hardware
- software versions
- load on the cluster
- sharding and replication strategies
- type of the data
- amount per document, shard and replica
- type of the compression used
- if data is in memory or is on disk
- if there are any dedicated indices
- and probably a few more things

Compression saves a lot of disk space but makes some queries run slower in some situations. The only way to get a meaningful answer is to run a set of experiments with the clusters and data you have.